# Business Logic Security in Web Applications

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security, business-logic

Some weeks ago I've asked a question regarding best practice on [how to secure a Business Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007337/make-a-method-of-the-business-layer-secure-best-practice-best-pattern).

In the meantime I have something based on `PrincipalPermission` and some custom code for specifics checks. But I'm still not really happy about that solution and struggling how to make it better.

What I'm still trying to achieve:

- Ensure that every method call is denied by default if nothing is declared on it
- Inheritance: Define basic permissions on a base class that get inherited
- Something that is easy to use for specific checks

I don't want to use OAP because it work on generic classes and has some limitations as well.

Additional question: Is there some kind of Security Framework that can be implemented withing applications?

I'm working with ASP.NET / MVC and targeting .net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Framework does not contain anything aside from `System.Security.Principal`.

There are some helpful suggestions, including ASP.Net membership, or roll-your-own solutions with example code, on [this earlier related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380336/asp-net-permission-authentication-architecture).

Comment: what about 3rd party security frameworks? can't believe there is nothing available on the market.